# codeigniter database how to limit the output

Tags: codeigniter, row, substr

Hello how can i like if i use substr(); do so i only get like 400 number of characters from the database out?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use core mysql function [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) to achieve this.

In codeigniter the query can be written as -

```
$this->db->select("SUBSTRING('COLUMN_NAME',5)");

$query = $this->db->get('TABLE_NAME');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    //process result here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use codeigniters limiter (test helper) to display only what you want

```
$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";

$string = character_limiter($string, 400);
```

You can pull the entire string out of the database but only use the number of characters you need.

Or 
take a look at this tutorial using "left" in mysql
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-blog-excerpts-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

It too late, but this is for someone like me looking for solution

```
public function getDetails(){
    // mytable(id,name,about,...,status)
    $this->db->select(array('id', 'name', 'SUBSTRING(about,1,180) AS about', 'status'));
    $result=$this->get('mytable');          
    return result_array();
}
```